# .NET queue ElementAt performance

Tags: c#, .net, queue

I'm having a hard time with parts of my code:

```
    private void UpdateOutputBuffer()
    {
        T[] OutputField = new T[DisplayedLength];

        int temp = 0;
        int Count = HistoryQueue.Count;
        int Sample = 0;

        //Then fill the useful part with samples from the queue
        for (temp = DisplayStart; temp != DisplayStart + DisplayedLength && temp < Count; temp++)
        {
            OutputField[Sample++] = HistoryQueue.ElementAt(Count - temp - 1);
        }

        DisplayedHistory = OutputField;
    }
```

It takes most of the time in the program. The number of elements in HistoryQueue is 200k+. **Could this be because the queue in .NET is implemented internally as a linked list?**

**What would be a better way of going about this?** Basically, the class should act like a FIFO that starts dropping elements at ~500k samples and I could pick DisplayedLength elements and put them into OutputField. I was thinking of writing my own Queue that would use a circular buffer.

The code worked fine for count lower values. DisplayedLength is 500.

Thank you,

David

Answer (score 8):

Queue does not have an `ElementAt` method. I'm guessing you are getting this via Linq, and that it is simply doing a forced iteration over n elements until it gets to the desired index. This is obviously going to slow down as the collection gets bigger. If `ElementAt` represents a common access pattern, then pick a data structure that can be accessed via index e.g. an `Array`.

Comment: Most of the LINQ operators that can benefit from indexed access check for the input implementing `IList<T>` (which `Array` does).

Comment: Just don't expose an Array as public though. It's way better to expose it as `IEnumerable<T>` or `IList<T>`, whichever one fits better.

Comment: @daqq I would add that if you need indexed access to your collection, then Queue is probably the wrong one to use; there's probably a bigger design issue in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the linked-list-ness is almost certainly the problem. There's a reason why `Queue<T>` doesn't implement `IList<T>` :) (Having said that, I believe `Stack<T>` is implemented using an array, and that still doesn't implement `IList<T>`. It *could* provide efficient random access, but it doesn't.)

I can't easily tell which portion of the queue you're trying to display, but I strongly suspect that you could simplify the method *and* make it more efficient using something like:

```
T[] outputField = HistoryQueue.Skip(...) /* adjust to suit requirements... */
                              .Take(DisplayedLength)
                              .Reverse()
                              .ToArray();
```

That's still going to have to skip over a huge number of items individually, but at least it will only have to do it once.

Have you thought of using a `LinkedList<T>` directly? That would make it a lot easier to read items from the end of the list really easily.

Building your own bounded queue using a circular buffer wouldn't be hard, of course, and may well be the better solution in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely the wrong data structure to use here. `ElementAt` is O(n), which makes your loop O(n<sup>2</sup>). You should use something else instead of a Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't think a queue is what you're looking for, but your access pattern is even worse. Use iterators if you want sequential access:

```
foreach(var h in HistoryQueue.Skip(DisplayStart).Take(DisplayedLength).Reverse())
    // work with h
```

Comment: It looks like he's going backwards through the queue, not forwards. But yeah, I agree. If you're going to do something in sequence you should use an iterator or something with O(1) indexing access.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to pop/push at either end *and* have indexed access you really need an implementation of [Deque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deque) (multiple array form). While there is no implementation in the BCL, there are plenty of third party ones (to get started, if needed you could implement your own later).

Comment: @Qwertie: a quick [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net+Deque) finds plenty, but I don't have time to review for quality to make something that could be taken as a recommendation.