# Efficient way to implement an indexed queue (where elements can be retrieved by index in O(1) time)?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, indexing, queue

Accessing items by index using ElementAt is obviously not a reasonable choice, as per [.NET queue ElementAt performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645250/net-queue-elementat-performance).

Is there an alternative generic data structure that would be appropriate for this requirement?

My queue has a fixed capacity.

As per [MSDN entry on the Queue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx), "*This class implements a queue as a circular array*", yet it doesn't seem to expose any kind of indexing property.

**Update**: I have found [C5's implementation of a CircularQueue](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/blob/master/C5/arrays/CircularQueue.cs). It seems to fit the bill, but I would prefer not to have to import another external library if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [cyclic array](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/queue/array/types.html). I.e. implement queue in array.

The implementation is pretty trivial, you don't need to use external library, just implement it yourself. A hint: it's easier to use `m_beginIndex, m_nElements` members than `m_beginIndex, m_endIndex`.

Answer (score 8):

```
public class IndexedQueue<T>
{
    T[] array;
    int start;
    int len;

    public IndexedQueue(int initialBufferSize)
    {
        array = new T[initialBufferSize];
        start = 0;
        len = 0;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T t)
    {
        if (len == array.Length)
        {
            //increase the size of the cicularBuffer, and copy everything
            T[] bigger = new T[array.Length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                bigger[i] = array[(start + i) % len];
            }
            start = 0;
            array = bigger;
        }            
        array[(start + len) % array.Length] = t;
        ++len;
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        var result = array[start];
        start = (start + 1) % array.Length;
        --len;
        return result;
    }

    public int Count { get { return len; } }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get 
        { 
            return array[(start + index) % array.Length]; 
        }
    }        
}
```